# Multiple Rewrite Conditions on multiple Domains with .htaccess-File

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm using a Webserver which is reachable via 2 Domains, eg. exa_mple.com and example.com. Let's assume, exa_mple.com is quite complicated so I'd like to redirect all traffic coming from exa_mple.com to example.com. Also, I'd like to force them to use https. That worked fine so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exa_mple\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Now when I try to open http://www.exa_mple.com/testfile.html, I actually reach https://www.example.com/testfile.html, which is absolutely brilliant. But now my task is to also make sure, this works with **subdomains**, so eg. testfile.exa_mple.com should lead to https://testfile.example.com and still point to the right folder.

SSL is available for all subfolders, I just need help finding the right Rewrite-Conditions. Allready tried lots of things, resulting in Server-Errors or non-working Rewrite-Conditions. Thanks for any help!